# How to fit an image next to presentation title?

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, titles, presentations

How to make the most out of an image, without resizing the title of the presentation?

Here is what I have so far, where I have the image below the title (etc.) and I resized it to 0.2:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{1em}% original: 2ex
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}% original: 2ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[High-dimensional visual similarity search: kgeraf]{High-dimensional visual similarity search: kd Generalized Randomized Forests}\author{}
\author[Avrithis, Emiris, Samaras]{Y. Avrithis, I. Z. Emiris, G. Samaras}
\institute{National \& Kapodistrian University of Athens}
\date{CGI '16, Heraklion, Greece}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{giraffe_sam} \\
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and the result:
[image]

While that is not bad, I was wondering if we could let the giraffe float to left (or maybe right) of the slide, without affecting the title?

Comment: So this spotted one is not a snake? ;-)

Comment: Nooo it's not a snake! It's a giraffe @PrzemysławScherwentke, which has an ε body-shape since we solve the approximate nearest neighbour problem (ε for approximation). :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not such epsilon-giraffe (May we have it here, please?), so there is another one as a picture:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{1em}% original: 2ex
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}% original: 2ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[High-dimensional visual similarity search: kgeraf]{High-dimensional visual similarity search: kd Generalized Randomized Forests}\author{}
\author[Avrithis, Emiris, Samaras]{Y. Avrithis, I. Z. Emiris, G. Samaras}
\institute{National \& Kapodistrian University of Athens}
\date{CGI '16, Heraklion, Greece}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
%\begin{center}
\begin{flushright}
%\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{giraffe_sam} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{giraf}
%\end{center}
\end{flushright}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you can accept some manual work, the giraffe may be on the level of the title and the rest:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{1em}% original: 2ex
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}% original: 2ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[High-dimensional visual similarity search: kgeraf]{High-dimensional visual similarity search: kd Generalized Randomized Forests}\author{}
\author[Avrithis, Emiris, Samaras]{Y. Avrithis, I. Z. Emiris, G. Samaras}
\institute{National \& Kapodistrian University of Athens}
\date{CGI '16, Heraklion, Greece}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
%\begin{center}
\begin{flushright}
%\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{giraffe_sam} \\
\raisebox{10mm}[0mm]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{giraf}}
%\end{center}
\end{flushright}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Well that picture you posted is lovely as well, so I will leave that post at rest, thanks again!